# ContentType application/pdf doesn't work in safari

Tags: c#, pdf

From handler I attach in response pdf document in memoryStream:

```
            context.Response.Clear();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdfByte);
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
        "attachment;filename=myDoc.pdf");
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
            context.Response.End();
```

In all browser work perfect, but in safari downloaded document has this name format=> **myDoc.pdf.txt**
Some proposal how solve?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I typically use for showing PDF files in a browser client:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

var data = new byte[(int)stream.Length];

stream.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));

var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = yourfilename,
    Inline = false,
};

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
```

This way is the only reliable way I could find to ensure all browser perform consistently. You should be able to use the header infor with Memory Stream